# how to set fancybox iframe height and width

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, fancybox, lightbox

I'm trying to adjust the height and width of a 'Fancybox' iframe lightbox but having no luck.

I'm using

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
$(".iframe").fancybox({
'overlayShow': false,
'frameWidth': 500, 
'frameHeight': 100, 
'type': 'iframe', 
});
</script>
```

html

```
<a class="iframe" rel="fancybox" href="http://form.jotformeu.com/form/40184565154353">This goes to iframe</a>
```

this is the page
http://www.thephotocabin.co.uk/proms/school-prom-enquiry/

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is what you are asking?

```
$(".iframe").fancybox({
'overlayShow': false,
'width': 500, 
'height': 100, 
'type': 'iframe', 
});
```